# push array into current key

Tags: php, arrays

```
foreach ($twt_f as $t => $value) {
            foreach ($posts as $p) {
                if ($t == $p['user']['screen_name']) {
                    // 
                }
            }
        }
```

$twt_f looks something like this:

```
[teamcanada] => 467865
[radiocanadainfo] => 420248
[el_mayer] => 169241
[nowtoronto] => 148360
[torontocomms] => 121720
[jimharris] => 113786
[globalnational] => 112365
[cdnpress] => 112038
[alexanderkenton] => 106188
```

i want to push $p into the current key of twt_f. how should i go about this?

Comment: `$t = $p['user']['screen_name']` is assignment, you probably meant comparison there. `==`

Comment: yes i meant comparison

Comment: What do you mean by push?

Comment: basically if the comparison holds true, then copy that array under that specific key

Comment: `$newArray[$t] = $p` inside if ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$newArray = array();

foreach ($twt_f as $t => $value) {
    foreach ($posts as $p) {
        if ($t == $p['user']['screen_name']) {
            $newArray[$t] = $p;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Pushing a value to an array:

```
$array["keyname"] = "Value";
```

Can also be done with 2 keys

```
$array["key1"][key2] = "Value";
```

Pushing a new value can also be done like this:

```
array_push($array,$value);
```

I hope this is what you searched for and answers you're question. Here is documentation of [array's](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)